# Installed ledgerstone around fireplace but doesn't look right - panel seams obvious - what did we do wrong?

Tags: tile, fireplace, remodeling, stone

I had 6 x 16 ledger stone panels installed and I'm surprised that the seams are so visible/obvious. I'm not sure if this is because of the source we chose, the install is poor/incorrect or this just how it is supposed to look? Is there something we should ask to be done or redone or get over it?

Edit to add two close up photos. The 'tiles' are 23.5 inches wide and the new ones are rectangular like a big tile-they don't have a 'staircase' like some ledger stone I've seen. They are definitely the same brand/style as I provided them to the tile contractor. The designer had them laid out like this in her drawings and the contractor followed as specified.  Is most ledger stone 'stepped'?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It almost looks like the ones in the middle are a different color/style. Do you have a link to the product listing? Generally, the edges shouldn't be straight like that so that they're not obvious. I'd venture that this was a poor quality installation.

Comment: what's the distance from seam to seam? ... maybe the installer cut off the ends

Comment: Panels like that can have different matched edges.  Matching the edges to make it look good can be the hard part.  A small section with limited pieces is harder than a full wall/s where pieces can be moved around.

Comment: I suspect the only way to get rid of the vertical joints would have been to remove sections of stone and rearrange the joints by hand to overlap stones along the joint.  Your contractor would have had to do a lot more work, and it might have required an extra panel to crib some stones from.